# Jpa repository query from foreign fields

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables that reference the same table with a ManyToOne relationship.
And I have a bidirectional relationship, cuz I have the entities defined in the table too.
How do I query the table taking as parameters fields of referenced tables ?
ie

```
clients
private Long id;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Description desc;


job
private Long id;
private String field;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Description descr;

description
private Long id;
private Integer salary;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="desc")
private Set<Clients> client= new HashSet<Clients>(); 
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="descr")
private Set<Job> job= new HashSet<Job>();
```

How do I write in the DescriptionRepository
findBy ( name from clients ) AND ( field from Job) ? MyResults should be fields from Job Table.

Something like
findByclient_nameAndjob_descr ?

Comment: You choose whatever name describes best what the method does, and annotate it with `@Query(...)`. Before doing that, I strongly suggest renaming `Clients` to `Client`, `desc` and `descr` to `description`, `client` to `clients`, and `job` to `jobs`. This will make your code and your JPQL queries much clearer.

Comment: Thank you. Will change them. But I meant whether there is a JPA method to have 
findByNameAndDesc( name,descr) - something like that. Whether it looks for the foreign fields too. Without a join or a Query

Comment: Even if there is, the method will have a horribly long, unreadable name, that doesn't clearly say what the method is about, and is coupled with the design of your entity. Automatic queries are fine for simple stuff like findByName, but for more complex queries involving multiple joins, you should use the Query annotation.

Comment: JPA has no such methods (findXXX). That is "Spring Data JPA" which is NOT THE JPA API.

Comment: Ah. Sorry.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a method like so in your `DescriptionRepository`

```
@Query("Select d from Description d where d.client.name = :clientName and d.job.desc = :jobDescription")
List<Description> findByClientnameAndJobDesc(@Param("clientName ") String clientName , @Param("jobDescription") String jobDescription);
```

**Note:** Not tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! this gives me an idea of how to do it! If I may ask,
If in job table, I have a Set with OneToMany relationship for another able. Would I be able to access a field there like 
d.job.FOREIGNSET.name ?Thank you again

Comment: Upvote and accept this as an answer if this has helped you in any way. Thanks.